# How to solve this trigonometry equation?

Tags: trigonometry

Show that $3(\sin θ - \cos θ)^4 + 6(\sin θ + \cos θ)^2 + 4(\sin^6 θ + \cos^6 θ)$ is independent $θ$.

This question was there in one of the cbse  sample papers  for class x . Tried many methods but couldn't solve.

I got the solution until I found the equation $= 13$ but couldn't understand the independent $θ$ part. It'd be great if you could explain that part. Thanks!

P.S it's question no.31.

[image]

PPS. A big thank you to everyone who helped

Comment: So, you started with an expression that has $\theta$s all over it; you ended with $13$ (which is correct), an expression with no $\theta$s in it. This means that the original expression has a value $13$ *regardless* of any particular value of $\theta$. This is exactly what "independent of $\theta$" means: the value of the expression *does not depend* on the value of $\theta$.

Comment: That makes sense but the QS states independent θ not independent of θ which is the reason I am confused. The only thing left is for me to assume there's a printing fault in the qs.

Comment: I believe it's a printing fault.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\sin^6\theta+\cos^6\theta=(\sin^2\theta)^3+(\cos^2\theta)^3$$

$$=(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)^3-3(\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta)(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)=1-3(\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta)$$

Now,
$$(\sin\theta\pm\cos\theta)^2=\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta\pm2\sin\theta\cos\theta=1\pm2\sin\theta\cos\theta$$

$$(\sin\theta-\cos\theta)^4=(1-2\sin\theta\cos\theta)^2=1+4\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta-4\sin\theta\cos\theta$$

Comment: I know that part but couldn't understand the independent θ part.

Comment: @Naina, Evaluate the given expression using hint to find that the result does not contain $\theta$